# Override __init__ of third party library parent class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the current (simplified) code structure:

```
########### 3rd party library ##############
class LibraryClassA:
    def __int__(self):
        pass


class LibraryClassB(LibraryClassA):
    def __init__(self, cfg):
        super().__init__()
        self.cfg = cfg

    def func(self):
        print("Do something")


###########################################

class UserDefinedClass(LibraryClassB):
    def new_init(self):
        print("The new init function")

    def func(self):
        print("Do something else")


def main():
    class = UserDefinedClass(cfg="CONF")
```

Basically I want to override the original **init** function of the `LibraryClassB` (that is a third party library class) and use a new init function defined in my class  `UserDefinedClass`.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I guess the `__int__` method in "LibraryClassA" is a typo? If so, do it in the same way as "LibraryClassB" overwrites the constructor of "LibraryClassA".

Comment: Define `__init__` in `UserDefinedClass`.

Comment: Python doesn't automatically call parent class initializers. If you don't call `super().__init__()`, it won't get called.

Comment: @MichaelButscher no typo. LibraryClassB calls super().__init__().

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych my purpose is to overwrite the init in the LibraryClassB. If I define a init in my UserDefinedClass, then I need to call super and the init of LibraryClassB is called.

Comment: @Gabrysse You don't have to call "super" but depending on what the constructors of the ancestor classes actually do you may have to do additional initialization steps to avoid errors.

Comment: @MichaelButscher unfortunately I have to mantain the super call since the classes are from a library, otherwise something could broke.

Comment: So basically you have to call the constructor of "LibraryClassB" to not break anything but you don't want to call it. I think this contradiction can't be resolved (or I am missing something).

Comment: @MichaelButscher yeah basically. I was thinking the same in the past days and to be sure I post this question. Thanks for your help, I appreciate that